# Can I use radio buttons/checkboxes in place of textboxes in a Javascript calculator?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, radio-button, calculator

I have a Javascript calculator in which users can enter quantities of products/features, and it will multiply the quantity by the set price.  Then, the result shows in a textbox below.  My 2 questions are:

1. I can use `<select>` options and specify a value for each one like this:

`<select name="SITE_EM_4.99" onChange="CalculateTotal(this.form)">
          <option value=""> - Select - </option>
              <option value="1">Yes</option>
              <option value="0">No</option>
            </select>`

However, it won't let me do the same with checkboxes/radio buttons.  How can I do that?

**Two**: Can I change the script so the total shows as actual text, vs in a text field? THANKS!

P.S. The script can be found [HERE](http://mcfedries.com/javascript/OrderTotals.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of having an input for the total just switch to a span (or something else) with an id (let's say "total"), and just replace it with innerHTML

```
<script>
function CalculateTotal(frm) {
...
document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = round_decimals(order_total, 2);
...
}
</script>
```

Comment: @medina-g: Are you saying having something like `<div id="total"></div>` and then in the script adding `document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = round_decimals(order_total, 2);`?

Comment: i just tried in jsfiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/NwkQW/1/ ) and it seems to work (i just copied and pasted your source code there so its messy hehe but look for "stackoverflow change" in the html window (two changes in total). Also you might need to do something like `code`document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "" `code` when resetting the form

Comment: OH!!!  It works now, and I see what I'm doing wrong; I had placed a link to the script rather than keeping it in the document (to save space), which caused the mess-up.  Is there a way to still link to the external script and fix it? When you do that in a form, you do formId.elementId...etc...  Can you give me an example of a way I could link to the `div`?  THANK YOU.

Comment: @medina-g:  Also, I want the calculated `div` to have a '$total' format. (e.g. $11.00)  However, if I try to put a $ sign before the `<div id="totalDiv></div>`, it displays the value as '$ total' with a space between the $ and the value (e.g. $ 11.00).  How can I fix that?  Thank you!

Comment: to get the $ in there you can do something like this `code`document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "$" + round_decimals(order_total, 2);`code` Now, it is important you understand what is going on, basically by setting the value of innerHTML of an element, you are wiping out any html/text inside that element.

Comment: @Caleb "When you do that in a form, you do formId.elementId...etc... Can you give me an example of a way I could link to the div? THANK YOU" Not sure what you mean...what do you mean link to the div?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it almost identically with radio buttons

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Milk" onClick="CalculateTotal(this.form)" > Milk<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Butter" onClick="CalculateTotal(this.form)" > Butter<br>
```

Second question, very easy to do.

Put an empty div tag with an id where you want to show the results. t

Then just insert the values into the div tag as text using javascript below after finishing calculations.

```
var output= document.getElementById("outputDiv")
output.innerText = {value of CalculateTotal()}
```

**EDIT: Requested Example**

```
<script>
   function CalculateTotal(myForm)
   {
      //do your calculations here 
      //...
      //...
      var text = //put whatev here that will be the output
      var output= document.getElementById("outputDiv")
      output.innerText = text;
   }
</script>

<body>
   <input type="radio" name="group1" value="1" onClick="CalculateTotal(this.form)" > Yes<br>
   <input type="radio" name="group1" value="2" onClick="CalculateTotal(this.form)" > No<br>
   <div id="outputDiv"></div>
```

Comment: @caleb that should do it for ya. GL

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="SITE_EM_4.99" value="1" onClick="CalculateTotal(this.form)">
```

Comment: I've tried that before, but it won't go to the previous value if you uncheck it.  Thanks anyway...

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
document.write("Welcome to my world!!!");
</script>
```

This function can be used to print text within the document itself instead of in a text field.

Comment: calling `document.write` after that page has finished loading will blow everything away.

Comment: @BearedO downvoted bc this will cause everything he is attempting to do to disappear of the page.